# Salesforce Einstein ChatBot

Tags: salesforce, chatbot, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-developer

can anyone help how we can integrate a chatbot in a collaborative way?
Ex- we need to create an einstein chatbot in salesforce, we are two developers one developer working on another chatbot change and one developer on another change.

How we can merge our changes in the chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming Developer A is working in Org1 and Developer B is working in Org2...

Have each developer login to https://workbench.developerforce.com

Then go to Migration->Retrieve in the menu system.

Upload the following package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>API_NAME_OF_DEVELOPERS_BOT_HERE</members>
    <name>Bot</name>
</types>
<version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

Then click next, next, and download the resulting ZIP file, and open it... each developer will now have their XML representation of their configuration.

Use GIT to merge the files together, and perform discretionary decisions on which sections win and lose when merging.

Now edit the package.xml file and replace API_NAME_OF_DEVELOPERS_BOT_HERE with the new name of the merged XML e.g. OUR_NEW_MERGED_BOT

Then create a package of new changes (effectively a ZIP file like this):

```
./src
./src/package.xml
./src/Bot/OUR_NEW_MERGED_BOT.xml
```

Then deploy the ZIP file using workbench (logging into the TARGET salesforce org this time):

Menu system: Migration->Deploy

Upload the ZIP and deploy to your target org.

Comment: Thanks Mark but, we have chat changes on sales force.

Comment: @RajMalviya I don't understand the relevance of your comment.